# Jetty Server blocks when setting handler

Tags: java, http, server, jetty

I am trying to setup a Jetty Server with Servlet Contexts and it blocks when calling `server.setHandler(context)`. If I run the code snippet from below, which is actually following the example from http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.3.x/embedding-jetty.html#_embedding_servletcontexts , it only prints one "a" and then blocks.

```
ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
context.setContextPath("/");

Server server = new Server(8070);
log.info("a");
server.setHandler(context);

log.info("a");
context.addServlet(EventServer.class, "/response");
context.addServlet(NotificationServer.class, "/notification");

log.info("a");
context.addEventListener(new ConfigureService());
context.addEventListener(new NotificationService());

try {
        server.start();
        log.info("Jetty-Server Started");
        server.join();
} catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(ExceptionUtils.getFullStackTrace(e));
} finally {
        server.destroy();
}
```

Any idea why it does not execute the rest of the code and blocks when setting the handler?

Comment: Your code snippet works fine on versions `9.3.22.v20171030` and the more recent `9.4.8.v20171121`.   Sounds like you have a corrupt set of jars or something.

Comment: The problem was that I had version mismatch with `jetty-servlet` and `jetty-server`. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that you can't actually run the `jetty-server` and `jetty-servlet` while them being different versions and this will cause the block when setting the handler.